# How to display categoryaxis label above the bar in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I need to display a category axis label or label above the bar in bar chart.and we have one label already showing on right side.is it possible to show like that.please find my requirement on below screenshot.

[image]

Please suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addLabel](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addLabel).

Please check the code below for an example:

```
chart.addListener("animationFinished", function (e) {

    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("amcharts-graph-AmGraph-1");
    var top = -64;
    var distance = 89;

    for (var i = 0, iLen = columns.length; i < iLen; i++) {
        top += distance;
        e.chart.addLabel(60, top, "Text");
    }
});
```